# xpath query with regex on node which contains some text

Tags: php, regex, xpath

**I want to get nodes which contain this text "$$$EXM_TAB$$$"**

```
$exampleNodes = $XPath->query('//*[contains(text(),"$$$EXM_TAB$$$")]');
foreach($exampleNodes as $exampleNode){
        $exampleNode->parentNode->removeChild($exampleNode);
    }
```

**Problem is I am not getting any node..
can anyone help please..
Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that you are properly initializing $XPath and it contains your document or it's part.
According the xpath statement - it looks absolutely fine.
So, I would suggest you to debug and to see your $XPath variable.
It might be something like this:

```
$doc->Load('data.xml');

$XPath = new DOMXPath($doc);
```

Comment: I have loaded html file. and trying to find node in that

Comment: Try to debug it and to see if it was loaded properly. Sometimes it turns out to be difficult to specify proper paths in web applications (especially in different CMS).

Comment: Please, write your solution here if you will got it, so other people will be able to see how to solve this issue.